# Laravel InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Trailing data with SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

I am updating my `laravel 5.2` application from MYSQL to SQL database, I have been facing carbon dateformat issues following this exception.

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Trailing data
```

and stack trace looks like this,

```
in Carbon.php line 425
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', '2016-11-20 13:56:28.0000000') in Model.php line 2990
at Model->asDateTime('2016-11-20 13:56:28.0000000') in Model.php line 2668
at Model->getAttributeValue('created_at') in Model.php line 2634
```

When I remove the trailing four zeros in carbon.php file for debug purpose, problem gets resolved.

Any idea of how to resolve this on model end or any other solution??

Comment: Don't change carbon.php. Check your date field fromatting

Comment: Nazmul, I just did it for debug purpose, I have reverted it back.

Comment: Ok..I have facing this problem many times. The problem occurs when we format a date using carbon that is not correct with carbon syntax. So check which date you convert using carbon. Or You can share your code of model & controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a microseconds, try putting this in your Model file.

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
```

Seems like it's a `datetime2` format, try using

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s+';
```

Comment: Thanks @steD, It was exactly the datetime2 issue. I have changed my DB schema to datetime.

Answer (score 2):

When laravel trying to convert plain text string to Carbon object, it calls this to get format:

```
/**
 * Get the format for database stored dates.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return $this->dateFormat ?: $this->getConnection()->getQueryGrammar()->getDateFormat();
}
```

Which means, you have a few options:

1. In every model files that you have created, provide the protected `dateFormat` property so it feeds the format correctly, or
2. Extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class and make a base `Model` class that has `dateFormat` set, and you create and extend model classes from it.
3. (Complicated but correct) extend the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar` to provide the dateFormat that suits your need, and tells Eloquent to use your grammar instead of built in SqlServerGrammar.

Good luck!

Comment: Nice explanation!