# Laravel Trailing Data Exception when model save or update

Tags: php, laravel, model, trailing, invalidargumentexception

I have problem with update the model data in laravel 5.6,
After many time I find that actually problem is with created_at and updated_at.
My code:

```
$editStuState = StuAtt::where('studentId' , '=' , 1007)->first();
dd($editStuState -> created_at);
```

and `dd($editStuState)`

```
StuAtt {#382 ▼
  #table: "stu_attendance"
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "3"
    "studentId" => "1007"
    "present" => "7"
    "absent" => "2"
    "leave" => "6"
    "created_at" => "2018-04-19 07:01:19.929554"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-19 02:31:19.000000"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "3"
    "studentId" => "1007"
    "present" => "7"
    "absent" => "2"
    "leave" => "6"
    "created_at" => "2018-04-19 07:01:19.929554"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-19 02:31:19.000000"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Error that appears when I print the `created_at` field:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data
```

Where is mistake and how fix it?

Comment: I use public $timestamps = false; in Model but it is not real solution for this.

Comment: Could you provide the entire exception?

Comment: @Quezler What ? I don't now your mean?

Comment: the errors should also include line numbers and a stack trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425: Trailing data with SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968572/laravel-invalidargumentexception-in-carbon-php-line-425-trailing-data-with-sql)

Comment: @Quezler   61
InvalidArgumentException 
…/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php603

Comment: hmm, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968572/laravel-invalidargumentexception-in-carbon-php-line-425-trailing-data-with-sql)

Comment: @Quezler Thanks for your time it is true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trailing data is a Carbon error, it's because you probably use `PostgreSQL`, and DB's date returns milliseconds.

> "created_at" => "2018-04-19 07:01:19.929554"

You can add the following method to your (base) model.

```php
    // ...

    public function getDateFormat()
    {
         return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';
    }
}
```